# Ni siquiera habrá que "pagar en mano" ni buscar dinero al hacerse todo desde el móvil

Tags: expresiones

¿Son sinónimas las expresiones "[pagar en mano](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.xataka.com/basics/que-significa-vtc-cuales-diferencias-taxis/amp)" y "pagar en efectivo"? ¡Muchas gracias!

"Sin embargo, pese a eso Uber y Cabify cuentan con la ya mencionada certidumbre a su favor, ya que los usuarios sabrán el coste total de los trayectos antes de contratarlos, y ni siquiera habrá que pagar en mano ni buscar dinero al hacerse todo desde el móvil."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesariamente. De acuerdo al mensaje que el texto quiere transmitir, 'pagar en mano' debe ser interpretado como el acto de realizar el pago en el mismo lugar y momento en el que se finaliza la consumación del servicio, *pudiendo ser en efectivo o con tarjeta*. El autor quiere introducir el concpeto sobre una modalidad de pago 'virtual' o 'remota' en donde el mecanismo del pago está previemente estipulado y requerirá, a lo sumo, de una confirmación del usuario. A menos que reclames algo, ya está definido cómo y cuánto se te va a cobrar *antes* de subirte al auto.

Comment: Por si acaso alguien lo pregunta, sí, también hay taxis con posnet

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por las explicaciones de Ustedes!

Answer (score 1):

Sí. En este caso, pagar *en mano* tiene el significado literal de pagar por el procedimiento de poner dinero en la mano del deudor. En general, "en mano" se refiere a dar algo a alguien personalmente, sin intermediarios y sin utilizar métodos indirectos como un buzón o (en este caso) una cuenta bancaria.